# TensorFlow "Please provide as model inputs a single array or a list of arrays"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[image]

This is the error and data I entered into my model. I just can't figure out why it won't work since the dimensions are okay and it literally prints a list of arrays.

My Model + Code before:

```
import numpy as np

training = np.array(training)

training_inputs = list(training[:,0])
training_outputs = list(training[:,1])

print("train inputs ", training_inputs)
print("train outputs ", training_outputs)


# Now lets create our tensorflow model

# In[10]:


from tensorflow.python.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(training_inputs[0], activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(len(training_outputs[0]), activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy', 'loss']
)

model.fit(x=training_inputs, y=training_outputs,
          epochs=10000,
          batch_size=20,
          verbose=True,
          shuffle=True)
model.save('models/basic_chat.json')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an input layer to your model:

```
...
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(15, activation='linear', input_shape=( len(training_inputs[0]),)))
    model.add(Dense(15, activation='linear'))
...
```

Comment: When copying my code you are missing a comma after `len(training_inputs[0])`.

Comment: Please try again.

Comment: Can you convert `training_inputs` to a numpy array and give us its shape please?

Comment: the print gave out this: "(18,)"

Comment: That explain the error but it is incompatible with your screenshot at the top of the question that shows `x` fed a 2d array when calling `model.fit`

Comment: I changed the list() to np.array() as you said? This is the current state of the code:

Comment: I managed to reproduce the error, and to remove it by using:
`training_inputs = training[:,0];
training_outputs = training[:,1]
`

Comment: I removed the `list` basically.

Comment: I still get the same error. I tried it with removing the np.array() in the fit method and with bot won't work. I removed the list() in the code too

Comment: Kept the list() added an np.array when inputting it into the model, now works. I've done the same before on my laptop it doesn't work, now I've tried on my PC it works. Fuck python

Comment: Glad you got there, I could not reproduce the error after our last messages.

Answer (score 1):

```
training_inputs = np.array(training[:,0])
training_outputs = np.array(training[:,1])
```